# MATLAB - Permutations of random indices in specific areas of a grid

Tags: algorithm, matlab, permutation

I have a problem in which I have 4 objects (1s) on a 100x100 grid of zeros that is split up into 16 even squares of 25x25.
[image]
I need to create a (16^4 * 4) table where entries listing all the possible positions of each of these 4 objects across the 16 submatrices. The objects can be anywhere within the submatrices so long as they aren't overlapping one another. This is clearly a permutation problem, but there is added complexity because of the indexing and the fact that the positions ned to be random but not overlapping within a 16th square. Would love any pointers!

What I tried to do was create a function called "top_left_corner(position)" that returns the subscript of the top left corner of the sub-matrix you are in. E.g. top_left_corner(1) = (1,1), top_left_corner(2) = (26,1), etc. Then I have:

```
        pos = randsample(24,2);
        I = pos(1)+top_left_corner(position,1);
        J = pos(2)+top_left_corner(position,2);
```

The problem is how to generate and store permutations of this in a table as linear indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First using `ndgrid` cartesian product generated in the form of a `[4 , 16^4]` matrix `perm`. Then in the while loop random numbers generated and added to perm. If any column of perm contains duplicated random numbers ,random number generation repeated for those columns until no column has duplicated elements.Normally no more than 2-3 iterations needed. Since the [100 ,100] array divided into 16 blocks, using `kron` an index pattern like the 16 blocks generated and with the `sort` function indexes of sorted elements extracted. Then generated random numbers form indexes of the pattern( 16 blocks).

```
C = cell(1,4);
[C{:}]=ndgrid(0:15,0:15,0:15,0:15);
perm = reshape([C{:}],16^4,4).';

perm_rnd = zeros(size(perm));
c = 1:size(perm,2);
while true
    perm_rnd(:,c) = perm(:,c) * 625 +randi(625,4,numel(c));
    [~ ,c0] = find(diff(sort(perm_rnd(:,c),1),1,1)==0);
    if isempty(c0)
        break;
    end
    %c = c(unique(c0));
    c = c([true ; diff(c0)~=0]);
end
pattern = kron(reshape(1:16,4,4),ones(25));

[~,idx] = sort(pattern(:));
result = idx(perm_rnd).';
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, that's absolutely awesome. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: I might add that I ultimately did something a little different to generate 'perm_rnd' because it wasn't quite getting the permutation I needed. 
'range = 0:15;
combinations = permn(range,4);
perms = transpose(combinations);
perm_rnd = zeros(size(perms));'

which was using the permn function that can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-permn-v--n--k-)

Comment: there is no difference. both generate cartesian product since numel(0:15)>4